# "0xDEADBEEF" - Signed or Unsigned?

Tags: unsigned, signed

I wanna know whether a hex number "0xDEADBEEF" is a 32-bit signed number or unsigned number. Because a 32-bit singed number ranges from -2,147,483,648  -  2,147,483,647 but it is 3,735,928,559 so anyone know about this?

Answer (score 3):

Neither. Sign-ed-ness isn't a property of a set of bits. It's an interpretation layer you impose on top of bits, which inform how you read them.

If you're reading this in a context where you expect these bits to encode an unsigned 32 bit integer, then they have a decimal value of `3,735,928,559`.

But if you instead read them in a context where you expect thse bits to encode a signed 32 bit ingeger, then they have a decimal value of `-559,038,737`.

Comment: how it will be 559,038,737 in case of signed?

Comment: @SameedAhmad I forgot the `-`. Fixed.